# Uninstalling Marklogic without Package Installer?

Tags: marklogic, uninstallation, marklogic-10

How can I uninstall Marklogic on windows when I no longer have the package installer .msi file? The only things I've been able to find online about uninstallation have said to use control panel -> add/remove programs. But I'm met with an error message while using that, saying it needs the .msi file. I've tried using new version's files with no luck. The version I need is no longer available on MarkLogic's website.

Add/Remove programs does not work without the .msi file. Cannot install a newer version on top of existing version, and deleting the installation location does not work either.

Comment: Why not download the .msi for that (currently installed) version and then use it to uninstall?

Comment: That version is no longer currently available for download on the MarkLogic website. It was before the log4j security issue, so they no longer offer anything before the fixed version.

Comment: Open a MarkLogic Support ticket https://help.marklogic.com/ and explain why you need the older version, and they should be able to provide it to you